# Cluster PAM in R - How to ignore a Column/variable but still keep it

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I would like to use the Cluster PAM algorithm in R to cluster a dataset of around 6000 rows. 
I want the PAM algorithm to ignore a column called "ID" (Not use it in the clustering) but i do not want to delete that column. I want to use that column later on to combine my clustered data with the original dataset. 
basically what i want is to add a cluster column to the original dataset. 
I am want to use the PAM as a data compression/variables reduction method. I have 220 variables and i would like to cluster some of the variables and reduce the dimensionality of my dataset so i can apply a classification algorithm (Most likely a tree) to classify a problem that i am trying to solve. 
If anyone knows a way around this or a better approach, please let me know. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import data

```
data <- read.table(“sampleiris.txt”)
```

execution

```
result <- pam(data[2:4], 3, FALSE, “euclidean”)
```

Here subset [2:4] is done considering id is the first column.And the below code should fetch you the cluster values from PAM. you can the add this as a column to your Data

```
result$silinfo[[1]][1:nrow(pam.result$silinfo[[1]])]
```

Comment: Thank you for the great code.Can you kindly explain the last code, the one that fetch the result.

Answer (score 0):

Their is a small problem in the above code.
You should not use the silhouette information because it re-orders the rows as a preparation for the plot.
If you want to extract the cluster assignment while preserving the original dataset order and adding just a column of cluster assignment you should use $cluster. I tried it and it works like a charm.

This is the code:

```
    data<- swiss[4:6]
    result <- pam(data, 3)
    summary (result)
    export<-result$cluster
    swiss[,"Clus"]<- export
    View(export)
    View(swiss)
```

Cheers